# iMac user can't access NFS mounted home directories with sudo

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, permissions, osx-lion, home-networking, nfs

I've just reinstalled my iMac on my home network, and have mounted the user home directories via a NFS share (hosted on an Ubuntu server).

The problem I have is that when I use sudo, I get permission denied to my own home directory.

My UID is 501 and I'm allowed to use sudo by virtue of me being a member of the Admin group (GID 80).

On the Ubuntu server, I've configured my home directory as follows:

```
Ubuntu# ls -ln | grep bryan
drwxrwx--- 35 501 80 4096 2012-01-27 14:09 bryan
```

Which translates correctly on the mac:

```
iMac$ ls -l | grep bryan
drwxrwx---  35 bryan    admin   4.0K 27 Jan 14:09 bryan/
```

As root is also a member of admin (GID 80), I'd have expected sudo to have allowed access to my home directory, but as you can see below, this isn't the case.

```
iMac$ whoami
bryan
iMac$ sudo bash
bash: /Volumes/home/bryan/.bashrc: Permission denied
iMac# whoami
root
iMac# cd /Volumes/home/bryan/
bash: cd: /Volumes/home/bryan/: Permission denied
```

Just to confirm, the following is the relevant part of output from `dscacheutil -q group` on my iMac:

```
name: admin
password: *
gid: 80
users: root bryan
```

What can I do to enable access to my home directory on the iMac when using sudo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `sudo`, you are switching to the `root` user (uid 0) – you *lose* your `brian` UID and the `admin` group. (`sudo id` will show you the exact values.)

Since previous NFS versions (v3 and older) performed all security checks on the client side only, there is a safeguard built in to protect against dishonest clients – when the client says your UID is 0, you do *not* receive root permissions – **instead, the NFS server sees you as the user `nobody`.**

To disable this safeguard, edit the server's `/etc/exports` to have the `no_root_squash` option, then rerun `exportfs -ra` and remount the share on all clients.

---

When testing NFS permissions, it is useful to have a world-writable directory on your share. For example, on Ubuntu, `sudo mkdir /home/temp; sudo chmod a+rwx /home/temp`. Then on OS X you could run `sudo touch /Volumes/home/temp/testfile` and instantly see what owner the newly created file has.

Comment: but doesn't the fact that root belongs in the group admin (GID 80) not grant permission, or does NFS not not take group permissions into account?

Comment: @Bryan: I'm not sure the groups on client host matter, in the case of root_squash.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. Security isn't really an issue on my home network, so I'll add the `no_root_squash` option.